# Position stack of div in column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three div contained in one, making a box. I have five boxes.
I would find a solution in CSS or in jQuery to display them In 3 columns instead of only one.This without picking out any line of code from the current structure (however I can add some).
Here is the JSFiddle :

```
<div class = "box">
    <div class = "boxTitle"> My title</div>
    <div class = "boxContent"> My content</div>
    <div class= "botBottom"> &nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <div class = "boxTitle"> My second title</div>
    <div class = "boxContent"> My second content</div>
    <div class= "botBottom"> &nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fayastone/C8XGU/3/

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you very much for reading me,

Hugo.

Comment: .box{
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The responsive solution..

You can make a responsive layout using `column-count`, wrap your boxes with `<div class='columns'>` then use the below CSS, try resizing the window to see how the layout is dynamically updated:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/C8XGU/14/)

```
.box {
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
.boxTitle {
    color : #FF6600;
    border : 2px inset grey;
}
.columns {
    -webkit-column-width: 20em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-width: 20em;
    -moz-column-gap: 2em;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -ms-column-width: 20em;
    -ms-column-gap: 3em;
    -ms-column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
    -ms-column-count: 3;
    column-width: 20em;
    column-gap: 2em;
    column-rule: 1px solid #eee;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: I will use this one, as the others it works but your responsive solution is perfect. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

There are three conventional ways to do this.

## 1 - [Floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Floats work in all major browsers. If you're new to CSS, they can be a bit tricky to get used to (read up [clearing floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) and [check out SO for info too!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clearing%20floats)).

```
.box{
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;
    /* new stuff */
    float : left; 
    width : 30%;
    margin : 0 1.5%;

    box-sizing : border-box; /* for box layout */
}
```

**[Check out the updated fiddle using floated boxes!](http://jsfiddle.net/C8XGU/11/)**

---

## 2 - Using [`display:inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Another (arguably better) approach is to change the divs' `display` properties. `inline-block` is a good value because it doesn't force the box to stretch full width, but it still allows very flexible use of CSS on the div's box.

*Problem is that `display: inline-block` is not properly supported in Internet Explorer 7 or below.*

```
.box{
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;

    /* new stuff */
    display : inline-block;

    width : 30%;             /* for three columns */
    margin : 0 1.5%;         /* for box layout */
    box-sizing : border-box; /* for box layout */
}
```

**[Check out my fiddle using `display: inline-block`!](http://jsfiddle.net/C8XGU/15/)**

---

## 3 - Imitating a `<table>`

This one is more complicated, but it allows you to easily ensure that each column is the same height.

You need to wrap your columns in another element to serve as the column container, and then you just make a few CSS changes. You are forcing your divs to behave like a `<table>` using CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"><!-- new table wrapper -->
    <div class = "box">
        <div class = "boxTitle"> My title</div>
        <div class = "boxContent"> My content</div>
        <div class= "botBottom"> &nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "box">
        <div class = "boxTitle"> My second title</div>
        <div class = "boxContent"> My second content</div>
        <div class= "botBottom"> &nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "box">
        <div class = "boxTitle"> My second title</div>
        <div class = "boxContent"> My second content</div>
        <div class= "botBottom"> &nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display : table;
    width : 100%; /* ensure table takes full width */
}

.box{
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;

    width : 33.3%;        /* even out the width */
    display : table-cell; /* This allows them to be side by side */
}
```

**[Check out the `display: table-cell` layout on jsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/C8XGU/16/)**

---

Comment: Both are working, display inline is a good/the best of both solutions,however the bottom box in my code, with the framework behind, doesn't display well. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update to your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/C8XGU/12/

```
.box{
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
}
```

The css of the box class has been updated.

Comment: Same as Martin's solution for displaying inline, the bottom-box doesn't display correctly, must be because of the framework that might use a picture. However thank you for read me and your answer !

Answer (score 1):

You want the boxes to be in separate columns? Like this?

```
.box{
    border : 2px inset grey;
    border-radius : 6px;
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C8XGU/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this? `display:inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/C8XGU/10/

Comment: The probleme here is that the box is scratched on itself. However thank you for your answer ;) !